# Neovim/Lua: How to use vim.keymap.set with vim.v.count

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, lua

I'm trying to add a count to one of my keymap bindings.

`vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>o", vim.v.count .. 'o<Esc>')` does not work as expected.

My intention for this keymap is to insert `count` empty lines and stay in normal mode.

If I use the key combination `<leader>5o` only one new line is added and the editor is in insert mode. Only after I hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key myself 4 extra lines appear and the editor switches to normal mode.

How to correctly use `vim.v.count` with `vim.keymap.set`?

Also, when using this keymap, should I press `5<leader>o` or `<leader>5o`?

If I use `vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>o", 5 .. 'o<Esc>')` it works as expected. After pressing `<leader>o` five new lines are added and the editor stays in normal mode.

I've also tried to wrap the commands into a function `vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>o", function() ... end)` but it didn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you particular case I would do:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>o", 'o<Esc>')
```

If you type `3`<kbd>leader</kbd>`o` it will translate into: `3o`<kbd>Esc</kbd> which is doing what you want to do (the `o` command supports count).

In Neovim you can associate a mapping to a Lua function. You could do something like:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>o",
  function()
    for i=1,vim.v.count 
    do
      vim.cmd('normal! o')
    end
  end
)
```

The Vim mapping doesn't support the `count` per se. Vim is aware of the count and apply the count to the result of the mapping (like in the example).

Would the `o` command not support the count you could have done:

```
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>o", "@='o<C-v><Esc>'<CR>")
```

If you then type `3`<kbd>leader</kbd>`o` it will translate into: `3@='o`<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>`'`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Since the macro support the count it will translate into: `o`<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>`o`<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>`o`<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

If you need the count to be used not only as a mere duplication of then entire mapping you can define a custom command and map to the execution of that custom command (that command can make use of the count).

Here is an [article](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-mappings-that-accept-a-count/) that explain that in more details.

Comment: what does the `"n"` means ?

Comment: "n" here is for Normal mode mapping. Other values are "i" for insert mode or "v" for visual and select modes.